# Determinant of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

My professor earlier this week proved the following proposition but looking back at the notes I've taken I haven't been able to neither follow the demonstration nor understand the missing parts; so here I am asking for help... The proposition goes as it follows: Let $M\in M_n(\Bbb{K})$ be a block matrix as it follows:
$$M=\left(
\begin{matrix}%
    A & B \\%
    0 & C%
\end{matrix}
\right);A\in M_k(\Bbb{K}),C\in M_{n-k}(\Bbb{K})$$
Then, $\det{M}=\det{A}\det{C}$.